# NSString replace unicode characters

Tags: ios, unicode, nsstring, character

I'w working with a server and I have to download text to my iOS application. Only problem : all characters like "é à ç" are replaced by "\U008" for example. Is there a way to fix this problem, to replace this code by the right character ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to parse the received text (textToParse variable) with this one:

```
NSString *encodedString = textToParse;
NSString *decodedString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[encodedString cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];
```

Comment: It crashes : [NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString

Answer (score 1):

I tested some encodings and `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` fit well.

My test was:

```
NSString *encodedString = [NSString stringWithCString:"Você realmente deseja sair da área restrita" encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
```

Remember that the message has to be a C-string (`"string"`) and not an `NSString`(`@"string"`)

Answer (score 0):

You can get character buffer and validate each character like so:

```
- (NSString *) removeUnicode:(NSString *) unicodeString {
    NSUInteger len = [unicodeString length];
    unichar buffer[len+1];

    [unicodeString getCharacters:buffer range:NSMakeRange(0, len)];

    unichar okBuffer[len+1];
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(buffer[i] < 128) {
            okBuffer[index] = buffer[i];
            index = index + 1;
        }
    }

    NSString *removedUnicode = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:okBuffer length:index];

    return removedUnicode;
}
```

or you can use this sample:

```
NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]] invertedSet];
stringWithOutUnicode = [[stringWithUnicode componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

and you can create your own valid character set and get not allowed characters

```
NSString *allowedCharacters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: allowedCharacters] invertedSet];
```