# NSString and Unicode in COCOA MAC

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsstring, unicode-string

I am developing a MAC (COCOA) application, where i am inputting special characters like (............) but when i print that string it is converting into some unicode characters like this \u201a\u00c4\u00b6\u201a\u00c4\u00b6\u201a, I don't want these characters to be send into server, I want to send (.........).

How can i achieve this in MAC COCOA. I tried following links but no help:

[Using Objective C/Cocoa to unescape unicode characters, ie \u1234](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099349/using-objective-c-cocoa-to-unescape-unicode-characters-ie-u1234?lq=1)

[NSString replace unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704762/nsstring-replace-unicode-characters)

Comment: If you are sending it to Server, I assuge you are serializing it to XML, in that scenario some characters will be escaped.

Comment: Yes i am sending it to server in an xml format, but in response i am not getting the same characters and that is the main issue. 
Is there any way to fix the problem? So that i can only send the special characters rather than unicode characters.

Comment: I had almost similar thing, as i was bifurcating different records by some unicode (it prints as inverted ?) then I serialized and send, the server knew its unicode and it converted it back. So job was done. Have you tried this way?

Comment: If i prints the xml string while sending it into server it generates output as <TrackDesc>\u201a\u00c4\u00b6\u201a\u00c4\u00b6\u201a\u00c4\u00b6\u201a\u00c4\u00b6\u201a\u00c4\u00b6..</TrackDesc> But when i print the response received from server i get like this â¦â¦â¦â¦â¦.. So according to you i should serialize the xml string that i am posting into the server?